# The difference between (a -> Bool) and (a -> a -> Bool) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am currently learning Haskell and came across a type signature that confused me.

I know that:

```
(a -> Bool)
```

Is how a predicate is assigned in the type signature when using (Ord a) but I came across a type signature that is declared as:

```
(a -> a -> Bool)
```

Which according to what I found online is a type signature for inequalities but I am confused as to if they are for adding an inequality to a predicate, ie:

```
(> p x == True)
```

Or if they are just to declare inequalities by themselves.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `a -> a -> Bool` is a bool-returning function with two arguments. Examples include equality (`==`) and inequality (`/=`).

Comment: Those examples are for when the typeclass is (Eq a) but I am talking about when the typeclass is (Ord a).

Comment: It's still a bool-returning function of two arguments.

Comment: Most of the functions which define the `Ord` type class have type `a -> a -> Bool`. `(>)`, `(<)`, `(>=)` etc. All take 2 arguments of the same type and return a `Bool`, which is exactly what this signature means.

Comment: The question I am asking is, with this type signature am I able to declare an inequality with a predicate? eg)    '> 5 x ==True'

Comment: I don't understand the question. The predicate `x < 5` (which is what it appears you are trying to write, in an overcomplicated way) has type `a -> Bool` (with constraints that `a` has to be a member of `Ord` and `Num`), because it only takes 1 argument. (The term "predicate" returns to a function that takes one argument and returns a Bool. `a -> a -> Bool` isn't technically a predicate, but it could I suppose be considered a "predicate of 2 arguments".)

Comment: by the way, if you've written a function and are unsure what type signature it should have, you can let type inference work for you - leave out the type signature, load your script into GHCI and see what comes up with the command `:type f` (if `f` is your function)

Comment: @RobinZigmond The question that I am relating this two actually is asking for a predicate with two arguments. I was just unsure of how to implement this. You have cleared this up for me. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When some function has a typesignature `(a -> Bool)` it just means it takes a value of some unconstrained type `a` and returns a `Bool`, i.e. `True` or `False`. You can however restrict the type variable `a` and get something like this `Ord a => a -> Bool`, it restricts the polymorphic type `a` in that sense that `a` has to have an instance of type class `Ord`.

You can also partially apply functions. e.g `(>) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool` and when you partially apply `>` with `5` you get `(>5) :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool`. That is a new function that takes something that has to have the type class `Ord` as well as the type class `Num`, and returns `True` or `False`.

To answer your question, you can of course create a new function by applying a constant to another function. You also don't really need the `==` if all you want to do is, check if a number is strictly bigger than a constant.

```
f = (>) 5
f 4 -- True
f 5 -- False
```

I hope this helps you to get started with haskell. You should probably read some tutorial to get a good overview though. I can recommend [learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Comment: I was looking at the type signature of ' ( a -> Bool) ' as just being related to predicates, without realising that it is just taking a value that returns T/F. I understand now thanks to your answer!

Comment: @ReggieSnow `f :: a -> Bool` is a function, which takes a value `x :: a` and returns a value `y :: Bool`. so the value that `f` takes` (`x`) doesn't return anything -- it is `f` that returns a Boolean value `y :: Bool`.